# How should I deal with APP_KEY and APP_SECRET (Dropbox API)

Tags: ruby, security, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've written a simple piece of code using Dropbox API, which implies usage of APP_KEY and APP_SECRET of my app. Let's  suppose someone wants to use my app too. I create a github repo, push the code and so on, but, of course, I don't put APP_KEY and APP_SECRET **values**. Do users have to register their own instances of this application? Is there another way to deal? Maybe sharing APP_KEY and APP_SECRET is enough secure to let it be that way?

In other words, Dropbox prohibits usage of username-password pair for authenticating (while their own official app does exactly that), but I want (for example) to make a plugin for KDE's Dolphin for getting public links to files from context menu and user shouldn't even know about all these SECRETS, KEYS and so on. What should I do?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're using dropbox for and more so what your app does? From your question so far, I feel like dropbox might not be the best thing to use.

Comment: So you want to distribute a client-side application that makes usage of the Dropbox API using OAuth with a secret key, but don't want to distribute that secret key. And now you're asking how to distribute the app without compromising your keys. Right?

Comment: Sunny, as I already mentioned, it's rather small script and I use it just for retrieving shortened public links to files from within terminal emulator. I'm afraid, there isn't any other convenient (and cross-platform) alternative to Dropbox for today.

Comment: jonallard, I'm just new to this stuff, so I don't know any 'best practives' or common methods of dealing with things like this. By the way, if you are right, what's the origin of tradition of naming those values APP_SECRET and so on, if it cannot be secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode your key using [Dropbox API Key Encoder](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/spa/pjlfdak1tmznswp/api_keys.js/public/index.html) and use [dropbox.js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js) to decode it. That way you do not need to expose your secret key

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, the app key and secret should identify your instance/release of the app, not the code itself. So, if you want to release the code itself, e.g., on github, the app key and secret shouldn't be included. (One way to do this would be to keep them in a config file that the app would read from, but don't include the config file in the public repo.)

Then, when you release your app (i.e., to end users for general use), it can include the app key and secret embedded inside, not plainly visible to the users. Of course, the specifics here are a bit of a judgment call, based on the scenario. For example, non-compiled apps (e.g., shell scripts) by default make the source available in plain text, even when "released", so you'll probably not want to include them.

But alternatively, if any other developers wanted to use the code and build the app themselves (from source), they should register and use their own app key/secret.

Comment: Yes, Greg, I'm using it like a shell script currently and I can't see any other way than just to include that data into sourcecode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Figaro Gem to hide my Dropbox secret keys: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro