# How do I distribute a Python app which uses the Dropbox Datastore API without exposing APP_KEY and APP_SECRET?

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I want to create a Python command-line app which uses the Dropbox Datastore API. I have registered an app with Dropbox. I have the APP_KEY and APP_SECRET.

How do I distribute this app without somehow exposing the APP_KEY and APP_SECRET?

Note: Letting the users create their own apps is -definitely- not an option in this case.

Related questions which did not answer my question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857752/how-can-i-use-the-dropbox-api-in-a-open-source-project-without-requiring-separat
- [How should I deal with APP_KEY and APP_SECRET (Dropbox API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606988/how-should-i-deal-with-app-key-and-app-secret-dropbox-api)

Comment: What is the actual worry you're trying to prevent here? Stopping people from writing their own programs that can access your app's tables in their own accounts? If so, are you sure your data are really safe even if you don't expose the secret? After all, they can easily capture the data on the wire, or just modify your app to copy the same data locally, or anything else they want.

Comment: Please explain in what ways the other questions you've linked to failed to answer your question. Your question seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: @abarnert: I think the issue is that other people could use the key to write their own apps.  Dropbox wants you to keep your app key secret so that the app key mechanism remains effective as a way of controlling access to their API.  I don't know what the Dropbox API TOS is like, but I could imagine you could be blacklisted if a bunch of people start using your key to make lots of API calls.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Sure, that's a _reasonable_ worry, I just want to know if it's the asker's actual worry, instead of assuming.

Comment: @smarx Nobody on the other questions have offered a satisfactory solution for how to secure my APP_KEY and APP_SECRET on the client. They all rely on some form of obfuscation.

Comment: @JulianPistorius I think the answers are pretty clear that what you ask is not possible.

Comment: @smarx Do you still work for Dropbox? Can you ask them to add some documentation for how best to handle this situation? It's not clear at all what the best way is for a situation like this.

Comment: Yes, I work at Dropbox, as does Greg, who answered on the other thread.

Comment: So can you confirm that there is no way of creating a standalone app which uses the Dropbox API without exposing the APP_KEY and APP_SECRET?

(By 'standalone' I mean without requiring me to build a server component to negotiate a Dropbox token for future API requests by the app.)

Comment: @JulianPistorius This has nothing to do with Dropbox, but yes, I believe what you're saying is correct. (It sounds to me theoretically impossible to give someone an app but somehow prevent them from reading data embedded in that app.)

Comment: @smarx I think you misunderstand this question. I know it's impossible to prevent somebody from reading data embedded in the app. Given this, what is the recommended way for developers to securely authorize standalone Python apps with the Dropbox API? That's my question. See my answer below.

Comment: @JulianPistorius That's not the question you asked. If you have a new question, please create one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a standalone python program, you cannot hide the key completely, you can only obfuscate it (encode with base 64 for example).

If you want to prevent people from having access to your key, you have to put your key somewhere else (server ...) and either:

1) Retrieve it at runtime from your program (Even then it is possible for someone to access it inside your program)

2) Use your server as a proxy to make the calls to the API (then the key is secure)

Comment: It looks like there is not an ideal solution. You did give me an idea though. It looks like I might have to store the keys on a web app, and then ask the user to generate a token on the website which they can then store locally for all future API calls. At least in this case only the user's own token is ever exposed to traffic inspection or digging around config files.

Answer (score -1):

The Dropbox REST API does provide a way to accomplish authorization of a client app without exposing the APP_SECRET - you only need to store the APP_KEY on the client. It does this through the OAuth 2.0 *token authorization flow*.

From the Dropbox Core API documentation:

> OAuth 2.0 supports two authorization flows:
>
> - The code flow returns a code via the redirect_uri callback which should then be converted 
>     into a bearer token using the /oauth2/token call. This is the
>     recommended flow for apps that are running on a server.
> - *The token or
>     implicit grant flow returns the bearer token via the redirect_uri
>     callback, rather than requiring your app to make a second call to a
>     server. This is useful for pure client-side apps, such as mobile apps
>     or JavaScript-based apps.*

See: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oauth2-methods

Unfortunately the Python SDK does not support the *token flow* method. It only supports the *code flow* method. (As of version 2.2.0, updated September 17, 2014)

The unofficial JavaScript library uses this token flow method:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/

So either ask Dropbox to update the Python SDK to deal with this scenario or hack the SDK yourself to add this functionality.

Comment: I see no reason why the token flow would provide more security than using the code flow and exposing the app secret.